# resizable attribute of jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a code for image drag and resizing with jquery.
i can drag the image but i am unable to do image resizing .PLease help me  what mistake i have did in resizing.
I have written my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#action").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    containment: "parent"
  });
  $("#action").resizable({
    handlers: "all",
    ghost: true
  });
});
```

```css
#action {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#limits {
  background-color: lavender;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themses/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<div id="limits">
  <div id="action">
    <img src="http://drkeyurparmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dummy-article-img.jpg" class="image">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove s from themses in jquery-ui.css link

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Dynamically resize image</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#action").draggable({
            cursor: "move",
            containment: "parent"
         });
         $(".image").resizable({
            handlers: "all",
            ghost: true
         });
      });
   </script>

   <style>
      #action {
         background-color: #aaa;
         height: 200px;
         width: 200px;
      }
      #limits {
         background-color: lavender;
         height: 300px;
         width: 300px;
      }
      .image {
         height: 200px;
         width: 200px;
      }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="limits">
      <div id="action" style="display:inline-block"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="image"/></div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try kernal arora answer.

Comment: @vikrant i have updated my answer as you have added jquery scrpt file was wrong.

Comment: @vikrant http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themses/smoothness/jquery-ui.css  include nothing

Comment: @vikrant but how draggable was working even if wrong script ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking `div` ID take image ID.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="limits">
            <div id="action"><img id="idDragImage" src="/home/cp/Desktop/jquery/index.jpeg" class="image"></div>
 </div>
```

Take the element with id. following way

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#idDragImage").draggable({cursor:"move",containment:"parent"});
            $("#idDragImage").resizable({handlers: "all",ghost:true});
        });
```